# update instead of delete

Tags: cakephp

with cakephp, is it possible to have update sql action instead of delete (i would like to set some kind of flag, so it "looks" like it is deleted)?

tnx in adv!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's easy enough using callbacks. A less manual approach, though, would be to grab the [SoftDeletable](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/view/soft-delete-behavior) behavior and tweak it to meet any special needs you may have.

Answer (score 0):

Just create an delete / disable kind of column and update the same on delete, you would need to put condition delete / disable  true for all find queries